# Remove specific routes from middleware in SLIM

Tags: php, laravel, slim

I added middleware to my project

```
//Initiate a Slim instance
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//Add Middleware for authentication
$app->add(new ExampleMiddleware();
```

but, i want to leave some routes out of the middleware.
Here is my class:

```
class ExampleMiddleware extends Slim\Middleware {
    public function __construct() { 
    //Define the urls that you want to exclude from Authentication
    $this->whiteList =['/'];//This does not work
}


public function call(){
 $res = User::authenticate($token); //Verify user

    if ($res){

        $this->next->call();//Continue to execute the request    
    } else {
        $this->app->response->body(json_encode(['error' => 'denied']));
    }        
}
}

//Sample Route which returns a user from DB using Laravel
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
$u = User::find(22078);
$app->response->body($u->toJson());
});
```

How can i leave the for example the  '/' route out of the authentication process?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a Route middleware instead of Application middleware. A route middleware will be only called if the Route matches the current HTTP request, if you want middleware to be applicable only for Authentication related requests you can do something like this,

`$app->get('/authentication_req', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    echo ' Hello ';
})->add(new ExampleMiddleware()); //This will be only applicable for this Route`

If you have many routes simply use Group routes and create a separate group with the routes which has to be excluded from Authentication,

```
$app->group('/authentication', function () use ($app) {
 $app->get('/login', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->getBody()->write(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
 });
 $app->get('/logout', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->getBody()->write(time());
 });
})->add(new ExampleMiddleware()); //should be called like this /authentication/login

//Excluded group
$app->group('/home', function () use ($app) {
 $app->get('/first_page', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->getBody()->write(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
 });
 $app->get('/second_page', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->getBody()->write(time());
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the next middleware and return early if route matches your whitelist. Something like:

```
public function call()
{
    /* Check if uri is whitelisted. */
    if ($this->uriInWhitelist()) {
        $this->next->call();
        return;
    }

    /* Authenticate user */
    $result = User::authenticate($token); 

    if ($result) { 
        /* Everything ok, call next middleware. */
        $this->next->call();
    } else { 
        /* Handle error here. */
    }

}
```

You could also check the source of [slim-jwt-auth](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth/tree/master) for an actual example.